# Get Invoice count of sales by stores for the last three months

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my CustomerDetails table.

```
CustomerID      CustCodeID
25              1
65              8
35              2
112             8
45              2
975             8
364             1
48              8
69              1
97              8
33              1
11              8
93              2
10              8
21              1
65              8
74              2
53              8
```

This is my Fact_SalesMetrics table.

```
Date                                Sales #                     CustomerID
2015-03-23 00:00:00.000             42895                       25
2015-03-13 00:00:00.000             53920                       53
2015-03-23 00:00:00.000             44895                       65
2015-03-13 00:00:00.000             43920                       35
2015-03-23 00:00:00.000             48895                       112
2015-03-13 00:00:00.000             47920                       45
2015-03-23 00:00:00.000             46895                       975
2015-03-13 00:00:00.000             45920                       48 
2015-03-23 00:00:00.000             40895                       69 
2015-03-13 00:00:00.000             40920                       11 
2015-03-23 00:00:00.000             41895                       33
2015-03-13 00:00:00.000             49920                       21  
......
```

I wish to make output like below:

```
CustCodeID         March 2015
1                  4
2                  2
8                  7
```

Which means the customer who has codeID '1' has 4 orders on March, 2 has 2 orders and like that.

To make this happen, I queried like below and got it working:

```
select CustCodeID,sum(March) as 'March 2015' from (
select bb.CustCodeID, aa.March from (
(SELECT count(distinct([Sales #])) as 'March', customerid
FROM [SalesData].[dbo].[Fact_SalesMetrics] a
where date >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00.000' and date <= '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000' 
and  customerid in (select customerid from CustomerDetails)
group by customerid ) as  aa inner join (select customerid,CustCodeID from CustomerDetails ) as  bb on aa.customerid=bb.customerid  
)  
) as dd group by CustCodeID
```

Now I wish to calculate the invoices count for the last three months like below:

```
CustCodeID         March 2015       February 2015       January 2015
1                  4                ?                   ?
2                  2                ?                   ?
8                  7                ?                   ?
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: What does by mean? Can you please explain by query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have column of type `DateTime`, you need to convert it to `Month Year` format. Use [DateName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174395.aspx) in Sql Server to extract the monthname and year. You should then find the count of `CustomerID` and [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) with the new date format and `CustCodeID`. You should use this query as the source query for the table to pivot.

If the values of months are known in advance, you can use **Static Pivot** by hard-coding the column names

```
SELECT CustCodeID,[March 2015],[February 2015],[January 2015] 
FROM
(
    SELECT CD.CustCodeID,COUNT(CD.CustomerID) COUNTOfCustomerID,
    DATENAME(MONTH,[DATE])+' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,[DATE]) MONTHS
    FROM CustomerDetails CD
    JOIN Fact_SalesMetrics FS ON CD.CustomerID=FS.CustomerID
    GROUP BY CD.CustCodeID,DATENAME(MONTH,[DATE])+' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,[DATE])
)TAB
PIVOT
(
    MIN(COUNTOfCustomerID)
    FOR MONTHS IN([March 2015],[February 2015],[January 2015])
)P
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/295104)**

If the numbers of columns are not known in advance, you can go for **Dynamic Pivot**.

For that the first step is to get the column names to be displayed after pivot from the rows. In the following query, it will select the columns for the last 3 months.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(MONTHS) 
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT TOP 3  DATENAME(MONTH,[DATE])+' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,[DATE]) MONTHS 
                from Fact_SalesMetrics
                GROUP BY '01 ' + DATENAME(MONTH,[DATE])+' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,[DATE]),
                DATENAME(MONTH,[DATE])+' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,[DATE])
                ORDER BY CAST('01 ' + DATENAME(MONTH,[DATE])+' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,[DATE]) AS DATE) DESC
            ) c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Now execute **Pivot** query using [Dynamic sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '
            SELECT * FROM 
             (
                SELECT CD.CustCodeID,COUNT(CD.CustomerID) COUNTOfCustomerID,
                DATENAME(MONTH,[DATE])+'' '' + DATENAME(YEAR,[DATE]) MONTHS
                FROM CustomerDetails CD
                JOIN Fact_SalesMetrics FS ON CD.CustomerID=FS.CustomerID
                GROUP BY CD.CustCodeID,DATENAME(MONTH,[DATE])+'' '' + DATENAME(YEAR,[DATE])
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 -- Specify the values to hold in pivoted column
                 MIN([COUNTOfCustomerID])
                 -- Get the column names from variable
                 FOR [MONTHS] IN('+@cols+')
            ) p            
            ORDER BY CustCodeID;'     

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/295105)**